# Trying to align my android layout as shown in screenshot

Tags: android, layout

I am trying to align my layout like image1, but it is coming like image2. I am not sure where am i making mistakes. Can anyone suggest :

Below is my layout code :

```
<LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="#ffffff"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/facebook"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:paddingLeft="10dip"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_weight="0.5"
                    android:src="@drawable/facebook" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/list"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="0.5"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
                    android:paddingLeft="10dip"
                    android:text="Facebook"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                    android:textColor="#444444"
                    android:textSize="20sp" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/facebook"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_weight="0.5"
                    android:src="@drawable/ok" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="#ffffff"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/facebook"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:paddingLeft="10dip"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_weight="0.5"
                    android:src="@drawable/twitter" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/list"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="0.5"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
                    android:paddingLeft="10dip"
                    android:text="Twitter"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                    android:textColor="#4a82ae"
                    android:textSize="20sp" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/twitter"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                    android:layout_weight="0.5"
                    android:src="@drawable/ok" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Use android:gravity="center" for TextViews

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just modified one of your rows, use the same of second one

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/facebook"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:paddingLeft="10dip"
        android:src="@drawable/facebook" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight=".8"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="left|center_vertical"
        android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
        android:paddingLeft="10dip"
        android:text="Facebook"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textColor="#444444"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/facebook"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="right|center_vertical"
        android:src="@drawable/ok" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 2):

For your requirement try like this ..

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                  android:layout_width="match_parent"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  android:orientation="horizontal"
        >

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            />

        <TextView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:text="Android Hacker"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            />


        <ImageView 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="okay"
            android:layout_gravity="end"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
            />


    </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Quick fix:
Remove the `layout_weight` attribute from the left ImageView and set its `layout_width` to `wrap_content`.

The *right* way:
Each row should not be a LinearLayout containing 3 views. Instead, use a [CheckedTextView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CheckedTextView.html) which will contain the text and the check at the right side.

Now, to get the image on the left, in the CheckedTextView's XML use `android:drawableLeft="@drawable/yourIcon"`. You can adjust the padding for that image with `android:drawablePadding`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are assigning same weight to all the `Views` and hence they divide the space between them even if the `ImageViews` don't need it. Try using `android:layout_width="wrap_content"` for the `ImageViews` and check whether that works or not.

Answer (score 0):

There are more options how to fix it.

I suggest you to use only textview with left and right drawable

```
   <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/list"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
                    android:text="Facebook"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                    android:textColor="#444444"
                    android:textSize="20sp"
                    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/facebook"
                    android:drawableRight="@drawable/ok"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have given weight to the elements being aligned, and that too equally, so they are taking equal space. Remove this attribute and align your icon image to left by setting gravity to left. Next text will be aligned without any gravity and tick mark image will have gravity right.

Just set the right paddings and it will work.
    e.g.,

```
<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/facebook"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:src="@drawable/facebook" />

 <TextView
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:text="Facebook"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

   <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/facebook"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="right|center_vertical"
        android:src="@drawable/ok" />
```